# Conditional values at dictionary instantiation

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a library I am creating in python and some entries are set to the result of a division.  Unfortunately sometimes this denominator is zero

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 0
mylib = {}
try:
   mylib['test1'] =  5
   mylib['test2'] = var1 / var2
   mylib['test3'] = 6
except:
   mylib['test2'] = 0.0
print mylib
```

In this case the `'test3'` case is never run.  Is there a way to force the `'test2'` line to some default and continue on to `'test3'`?

You'll also note that I hardcoded here that `'test2'` was the problem child.  Is there a way to know which line was failing?

**EDIT**  One possible solution that I'd prefer to avoid if possible is to do a `try` for each variable in the dictionary individually but I'd like to avoid that if possible

Comment: Just move the lines that have nothing to do with the exception **out** of the `try..except`. There is no need to overload the `try` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would't bother with using a `try` statement. If you are aware enough of the possibility that `var2` could be zero that you can catch a `ZeroDivisionError`, you can simply write a conditional expression to handle it as a special case:

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 0
mylib = {}
mylib['test1'] =  5
mylib['test2'] = var1 / var2 if var2 else 0.0
mylib['test3'] = 6
print my lib
```

As a general rule when using a `try/except` statement, the `try` clause should contain code that can be considered to succeed or fail as a group.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function.

```
def safediv(x,y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return None

mylib['test1'] =  5
mylib['test2']=safediv(var1,var2)
mylib['test3'] = 6
```

Comment: It's not wrong, but it both obfuscates (a little) what is being done with `var1` and `var2` as well as adding the overhead of a extra function call.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

You could wrap each operation in a `try/except`, or shove the coverage into a function like [@trvrm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856538/249543) suggests, to avoid repeating yourself with multiple `try/except` blocks.

#### Option 2

I don't think you need the `try / except` block. If you know that `0` might be a possible and valid input, the use `if / else` to handle it instead. Exception handling is for truly exceptional situations, not situations where you can totally predict that this is going to happen.

I would suggest, at least as a starting point, to replace:

```
mylib['test2'] = var1 / var2
```

...with:

```
if var2 == 0
    mylib['test2'] = 0.0
else
    mylib['test2'] = var1 / var2
```

I guess my question is, "What's wrong with good old `if/else`?"

Comment: Exceptions are fine when the situation is expected to happen, just infrequently. See for instance the explanation here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing

Comment: @jefflunt There is nothing "wrong" I was just wondering if there was a clever python shorthand way of accomplishing the same thing with shorter code.  I actually really like the safediv recommendation given above.  But there certainly is nothing wrong with a `if/else`

Comment: Whoa, I wasn't suggesting it was wrong to use exception catching. Just asking why not use if/else?

Comment: It's great that @sedavidw has posted a code example, but I think we need to see a more realistic example of their actual code to decide on the best technique.